# How to create activity again in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making some game and I want to create activity again after click on  some Button.

For example:
I have activities A (game) and B (after game menu). I want to go back to activity A after clicking "Play again" in activity B. But I don't want to resume it but to create it again, so it starts from the beginning. Is there any way of doing this?

I am using android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are finished with an Activity you can destroy it. This means that it won't be running in the background. You can then call a new instance of the activity. This avoids creating and running several instances at the same time. I have created some basic code below and annotated it.

**Menu**

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}

    //Method called when button is clicked
    public void PlayAgain(View view){

        /*
        Start activity used to create the new activity
        Calling a new Intent to change from this activity to the GameActivity
        */
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));
        //Telling this to finish - ending the activity
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

**GameActivity**

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}
    /*
    Method called when criteria is met to end the activity
    eg: time limit or score condition
    */
    public void onGameFinish(){
        //Same as the menu button, changing activities.
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class));
        //Ending this activity when we are done with it.
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps - All the best.